# Domain and range of a function defined by $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Find the domain and range for a function $f$ defined by $f(z)=\log(h(z))$ where $\lbrace h: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \: \vert \: h(z) = \operatorname{Re}(z) + \operatorname{Im}(z) \rbrace$

**Here's what I've done:**

Simplifying the above expression, we have $f(x,iy) = \log(x+y)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thus $x+y>0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{Re}(z)+\operatorname{Im}(z)>0$

$\operatorname{Im}(z)>-\operatorname{Re}(z)$

$\therefore y=-x \Rightarrow z = x-xi = x(1-i) \\ $

So the domain is defined by the set:

$A = \lbrace x(1-i) \: \vert \: x \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$

If I've done this correctly and the domain is set $A$, then is the range $\mathbb{R}$? If not, how would I go about finding that?

Thanks

Comment: No, $A$ is only the border of the domain.

Comment: When you say $f(z)=\log(h(z))$ does $\log$ mean the real rather than complex log.  (the real log having the restriction that $h(z)> 0$ whereas the complex log only has the restriction $h(z) \ne 0$)

Comment: @fleablood At my university, log denotes the natural logarithm, so I'm assuming we are working with that.

Comment: That's a reasonable assumption.... You seem to have gone for noting that $y > -x$ but then immediately jump to $y = -x$.  I don't understand why.  You *know* $y \ne -x$ so why do you immediately assume it *does*. You *don't* want $A= \{x+yi | y=-x\}$.  You *want* $A = \{x+yi|y > -x\}$.

Comment: @fleablood My mistake, but I see that now, thanks. This site is for learning from mistakes after all :)

Comment: As for the range... Well, $z$ can be any complex number so long as the real components add to positive number and we can find such complex numbers that add to any positive real number, and so the range is the range of the $\log$ function which is all the reals.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah thought so, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is 
$$\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ \big| \ \operatorname{Im}(z) + \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0\}$$

It corresponds to the upper right open half of the complex plane (seen as $\mathbb{R}^2$), split in two parts by the line of equation $y = -x$. This line is the set $A = \lbrace x(1-i) \: \vert \: x \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$ that you mention.